# C++ Bubblesort dynamic stack

Tags: file, sorting, stack

How can I change my sorting function called bubblesort, so that it uses a dynamic stack. Now I've done and funcion can work properly sorted, but using the list, because I intercede for the next item and in stack i have access only to the top. Data for stacks are taken from external text files. Is it possible to do so to earn two elements of the stack to compare them, then save them in another stack or structure (without using arrays and STL) and so on until the entire sorts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int temp;
int br = 0;

struct stack 
{ 
    int key; 
    stack *next; 
} *start, *p, *s1 = NULL, *s2 = NULL, *help = NULL; 

void push(stack *&st, int n)
{

    stack *p = st; 
    st = new stack; 
    st -> key = n; 
    st -> next = p;

}

int pop(stack *&start, int &n) 
{
    if(start) 
    {
        stack *p = start; 
        n = start -> key; 
        start = start -> next;
        delete p;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void print_stack(int z)
{

    if (z == 1)
    {
            if(s1)
            {
                int a;

                while(pop(s1, a))
                {
                    cout << a << " ";
                    push(help, a);
                }
                 while(pop(help, a))
                    push(s1, a);
            }
            else
                cout << "Stack 1 is empty !";
    }

    if(z == 2)
    {
            if(s2)
            {
                int b;

                 while( pop(s2, b) )
                 {
                      cout << b << " ";
                      push(help, b);
                 }

                 while( pop(help, b) )
                    push(s2, b);
            }
            else
                cout << "Stack 2 is empty!";

    }

    cout << endl;

}

int bubblesort(stack *&S)
{

    stack *T;  
    int n, flag;
    int current = pop(S, n);
    if (S == NULL)
        return 0;
    do
    {
        flag = 0;
        T = S;
        while (T->next)
        {
            if (T->next->key < T->key) 
            {
                n = T->key;
                T->key = T->next->key;
                T->next->key = n;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
                T = T->next;
        }
    } while (flag);

    return 0;

}

void input_first(stack *st)
{

    int a;
    cout << "Stack1\n";

    ifstream i_file;
    i_file.open("stack1.txt", ios::in);
    if(i_file)
    {

        while (!i_file.eof())
        {

            i_file >> a;
            push(s1, a);

        }

        i_file.close();


    }
    else
        cout << "Error while opening input file!" << endl;

}

void input_second(stack *st)
{

    int a;

    cout << "Stack2\n";

    ifstream i_file;
    i_file.open("stack2.txt", ios::in);
    if (i_file)
    {
        while (!i_file.eof())
        {

            i_file >> a;
            push(s2, a);

        }
        i_file.close();

    }
    else
        cout << "Error while opening input file!" << endl;

}

int main()
{

    stack *test1 = NULL;
    stack *test2 = NULL;

    input_first(test1);
    print_stack(1);
    cout << endl;

    input_second(test2);
    print_stack(2);
    cout << endl;

    cout<<"Sorted first stack: ";
    bubblesort(s1);
    print_stack(1);
    cout << endl;

    cout<<"Sorted second stack: ";
    bubblesort(s2);
    print_stack(2);
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve it in C or C++? For now it is C+- the implementation will greatly depend on the language.

Comment: could you also try to rephrase, I have a lot of difficulties to read your explanations; for example. `Now I've done and funcion can work properly sorted`, cannot be parsed by my brain.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " Is it possible to do so to earn two elements of the stack"?

Comment: Briefly, sorting function works, but must be converted to work with dynamic stack.

Answer (score 0):

Example algorithm using a source stack, a destination stack, and a temp variable. Let s = source stack, t = destination stack. The algorithm finds the smallest value in s by shifting data back and forth between s and t (see the code below for how this is done), then pushes that smallest value onto t and repeats process until s is emptied. Then all values from t are pop/pushed back onto s.

```
    // s = stack to sort
    // t = temp stack
    // d = data
    // pop/push values from s to t, smallest to largest
    while(s){                     // while s not empty
        Pop(s, d);                // pop s into d
        while(t && Top(t) > d)    // push all t's > d back onto s
            Push(s, Pop(t));      //   to make a "space" for d in t
        Push(t, d);               // push d onto t 
    }
    // t now sorted in reverse order (pops return largest to smallest)
    while(t)                      // pop / push t to s
        Push(s, Pop(t));
```

This method has time complexity O(n^2). If a sort is done using a stack and a queue, or two queues, then a bottom up merge sort can be implemented with time complexity O(n log(n)). For linked lists, a small array (26 to 32) of pointers to nodes can be used to keep track of lists that double in size with each level of the array, array[i] is either null or points to a list of size 2 to the power i elements, again using a bottom up merge sort.